# Почему когда в инпут ввожу число программа работает, но стоит сделать проверку на строку к примеру "м" или "ж" Выполняется строго условие else?

Tags: python, if

Где 1 это мужчина, а 2 женщина
Стоит мне поставить вместо 1 букву "м", а вместо 2 - " ж" всегда выполняется else

```
    print('Добро подаловать в программу для высчитывания идеального веса!')


    w = input('Укажиие ваш пол буковй 1/2?:  ' )
    if w == '1':
        s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
        x = (4*int(s)/2.54-128)*0.453
        print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' +str(x))
    elif w == '2':
        s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
        x = (3.5*int(s)/2.54-108)*0.453
        print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' +str(x))

    else:
        print('Вы ввели неверное значение')
```

Вот код который не работает, всё тоже самое только меня цифры на букву, проверяю только нижний регистр пока

```
   w = input('Укажиие ваш пол буковй м/ж?:  ' )
   if w == 'м':
        s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
        x = (4*int(s)/2.54-128)*0.453
        print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' +str(x))
```

Comment: нет смысла задавать один вопрос, а код приводить другой. Приводите тот код, который не работает. И тестовые примеры, что вводите, что хотите получить, что получаете.

Comment: Давайте угадаю - вы вводите маленькие буквы, а проверяете большие. Или наоборот вводите большие, а проверяете маленькие.

Comment: Нет, изначально я так же делал проверку для маленького и большого регистра через or, решил упростить пока что бы понять в чем проблема , проверяю всегда через маленький регистр, так же как и в коде стоит проверка, но всё ровно уводит меня в else, но ничего не меняя кроме букв на цифры у меня код работает идеально

Comment: @ПавелКондур, а как проверяли, допустим, м или М? Если через `w == 'м' or 'М'`, то так не сработает :)

Comment: Я только начал изучать, и то что вы написали это буду делать в следующий раз, всё поступательно) сейчас в упор не могу понять почему пока не работает так

Comment: Приведённый код работает нормально, если вводить `м`, скопированную из кода, что не удивительно.

Comment: Значит дело в работе приложения, А писал я на телефоне :)))

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Ни какого приложения, ни при чем тут телефон. Но закончим на этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш код, но с изменёнными значениями на М/Ж. Не знаю что у вас не работало, я поменял символы только в строках проверок.

```
print('Добро подаловать в программу для высчитывания идеального веса!')


w = input('Укажиие ваш пол буковй М/Ж?:  ' )
if w == 'М':
    s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
    x = (4*int(s)/2.54-128)*0.453
    print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' +str(x))
elif w == 'Ж':
    s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
    x = (3.5*int(s)/2.54-108)*0.453
    print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' +str(x))
else:
    print('Вы ввели неверное значение')
```

Comment: Лучше поддержать и М/м с Ж/ж :)

Comment: Спасибо, видимо ошибка в приложение на котором я это делал, так как и этот код выполняет else, просто был вне дома и делал программу на приложение в андроид, приду домой и проверь на компьютере, так как делал тоже самое, в любом случае спасибо!)

Comment: Если помог, отметьте мой ответ(галочка справа от текста)

Comment: А зачем вообще что-то менять? Дополненный кусок кода автора тоже нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Код написан нормально, если проблема в том, что нужно написать в верхнем регистре, или добавить английские символы, то можно добавить словари с этими буквами перед твоим кодом.

````
print('Добро пожаловать в программу для высчитывания идеального веса!')


ms = {'m', 'M', 'м', 'М'}   # буквы М во всех регистрах
jis = {'ж', 'Ж'}   # буквы Ж во всех регистрах


w = input('Укажите ваш пол буквой м/ж?: ')
if w in ms:   # Проверяет если буква М в переменной w
    s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
    x = (4 * int(s) / 2.54 - 128) * 0.453
    print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' + str(x))

elif w in jis:   # Проверяет если буква Ж в переменной w
    s = input('Какой ваш рост? ')
    x = (3.5 * int(s) / 2.54 - 108) * 0.453
    print('Ваш идеальный вес: ' + str(x))

else:
    print('Вы ввели неверное значение')```
````